# Noun clause or adverb clause?

Tags: nouns, syntactic-analysis, adverbs, clauses

I was reading about noun clauses and adverb clauses and I am a little confused about what follows:

One grammar claims that the clause in bold in the following sentence is a noun clause working as an adjective complement:

I’m happy **that you’ve decided to come**.

Another grammar says that the sentence in bold in the following sentence is an adverb clause:

Many English speakers today are surprised **that Early English would be unintelligible to them.**

I am confused, because both clauses follow an adjective and, because they start with “that,” I think they are, indeed, noun clauses.
Moreover, the second clause doesn’t seem to work as an adverb, once it doesn’t answer “when?”, “how?”, “why?”, “where?”, etc.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: They are both _content clauses_ per one sect of grammarians, and _complement clauses_ per another sect.

Comment: You're assuming that it's one or the other, that it can't be both, that one must be wrong. That's an false assumption. Those are adjective complements. Adjective complements are noun clauses. Those adjective complements modify a preceding adjective. Since adjectives are modified by adverbs, those noun clauses are adverbial, ergo those noun clauses are also adverb clauses. It's like how "carpet" is a noun. When I put that noun before the noun "cleaner," it's a noun adjunct, i.e., a noun being used adjectivally, ergo "carpet" is simultaneously a noun and an adjective in "carpet cleaner."

Comment: That's nonsense. Note that the _that_ clauses are not modifiers, but complements of the adjectives "happy" and "surprised". And in "carpet cleaner", the noun "carpet" is not being used adjectivally, but is a nominal modifying "cleaner".

Comment: Thanks for your answers!

Comment: @Benjamin Harman: In _carpet-cleaner_, _carpet_ is a noun adjunct modifying _cleaner._

Answer (score 2):

> [1] *I’m happy* [*that you’ve decided to come*].
>
> [2] *Many English speakers today are surprised* [*that Early English would be*
> *unintelligible to them*].

I would strongly recommend dropping the terms 'noun clause', 'adverb clause' etc. The classification of finite subordinate clauses is based on their internal form rather than spurious analogies with the parts of speech.

In both your examples, the bracketed expressions are **declarative content clauses** functioning as **complement** of the adjectives "happy" and "surprised".

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and suggestion. I've just started studying Syntax. I will drop these terms and study finite and non-finite clauses.

Comment: Thank you very much, @BillJ! Makes sense!